# How to change one line but keep another?

Tags: javascript

I have two elements with the same class - I would like to remove one, but keep another.

For example, I would like to keep this tag:

`<div class="chat-column-head chat-container"></div>`

But remove this one:

`<div class="chat-column-head"></div>`

I'd prefer to use this sort of method since I know little about jQuery.

`document.querySelector(".id")`

Comment: You can't have two DIVs with the same ID.

Comment: Neither of your DIVs has an ID. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: they had two and i'm attempting to remove one using javascript surely theres some way to remove the bottom one.

Comment: well sorry i'm new to this "class" lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll(".chat-column-head:not(.chat-container)");
// then iterate over returned list and remove all elements
Array.prototype.forEach.call( elementList, function( node ) {
   node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
});
```

Comment: would `document.querySelectorAll(".chat-column-head:not(.chat-container)").remove();` work? to remove the class without affecting .chat-container that is

Comment: .querySelectorAll returns a frozen NodeList. You need to iterate over it and do things. Look I've modified the answer

Answer (score 3):

What you call an "id" is actually called **a class name**.
You can try this :

```
document.querySelector(".chat-column-head:not(.chat-container)")
```

It'll select the first `.chat-column-head`s element that doesn't have the `.chat-container` class.